# Insert image from table to another with different database

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a table named studeny_image(admissionformNO,Image) in database . i need to get image from this table to another table named studentphoto (studentID,Photo) in another database using sqldatareader in VB.net?

Comment: I would use streamreader..

Comment: What have you tried so far? What RDBMS are you using? (SQL-Server, MySQL, Access, etc.)?

Comment: What is your question? I see a question mark, but it appears to be at the end of a statement.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani, you would be wrong to do that.  A `StreamReader` is for reading text from a `Stream`, most often a `FileStream`.  What possible use could that have in this case?

Comment: @jmcilhinney...Thanks for the correction...I meant to MemoryStream and FileStream